# Opencv camera calibration sample goodInput always false

Tags: opencv

I am trying the camera calibration sample according to http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html, but it always failed with `goodInput` checking. The default configure file is like as bellow. I tried relative path and absolute path, none of them worked. I guess maybe number of images 5 is small, I repeated these lines in the configure file, didn't help. What does it check? Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<images>
c:/Qt/my_proj/CameraCalibrationConsole/DSC_0003.jpg
c:/Qt/my_proj/CameraCalibrationConsole/DSC_0004.jpg
c:/Qt/my_proj/CameraCalibrationConsole/DSC_0005.jpg
c:/Qt/my_proj/CameraCalibrationConsole/DSC_0006.jpg
c:/Qt/my_proj/CameraCalibrationConsole/DSC_0007.jpg
c:/Qt/my_proj/CameraCalibrationConsole/DSC_0003.jpg
c:/Qt/my_proj/CameraCalibrationConsole/DSC_0004.jpg
c:/Qt/my_proj/CameraCalibrationConsole/DSC_0005.jpg
c:/Qt/my_proj/CameraCalibrationConsole/DSC_0006.jpg
c:/Qt/my_proj/CameraCalibrationConsole/DSC_0007.jpg
</images>
</opencv_storage>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be \ instead of / since it is in windows? not sure here, but if this is the case you may also need to escape it...

Comment: Hi @api55 , I tried that also. The configuration file default.xml can be found, if I use / or \\ in the absolute path, or if I use relative path. I don't know what it is checking. I don't know if it is because files are not found, or some other reasons. I am a beginner to opencv, I don't know class FileStorage.